# The HTTP status code "0" is not valid

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

The HTTP status code "0" is not valid.

```
public function filter()
{
$institute = (new Institute)->newQuery();
$institute->with(['locations','courses' =>  function ($query) use ($request){
            $query->with('trainers');
        }]);
}
$data = $institute->get();
if(count($data) > 0)
{
    return response()->json($data);
}
else
{
    return response()->json(404,'No Data found');
}
}
```

Actually, I want to display error 404 message if there is no data,

my problem is when I try to check whether data is there or not I'm getting an error called  InvalidArgumentException.Can anyone help on this please.

Comment: Can you paste the full error you received?

Comment: isn't it `response()->json([], 404)` ? first argument should be data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
return response()->json(404,'No Data found');
```

The first argument of json should be data, then goes a status code. In this case the status code gets 0 value. Simply do it as follows:

```
return response()->json('No Data found', 404);
```

Comment: I think it should be `response()->json($data, 404)`

Comment: oh, yeah! You're write, I mixed up their positions.

Comment: In my case, i tried to get exception error code and to pass it, like `$e->getCode()` what is silly :/ Just in case someone did the same...

Answer (score 4):

This error is thrown when you try and use 0 as your response exception code. In my case my `App/Exceptions/Handler.php` file was modified and I returned 0 as my HTTP code after formatting which is not allowed. Just make sure you are returning a valid HTTP code from your Exception handler at all times.

Comment: I know this isn't marked as the solution but I struggled for like 30 minutes because my Handler returned the exception code as HTTP Code. Thanks for saving me!

Answer (score 1):

Another case can cause the same problem when you have a difference between code and database schema.

Answer (score 0):

In laravel, I had this issue when trying to do an `insert` on a table where I had the field type incorrect. In my specific case, I was trying to insert a `varchar` into an `integer` field in my DB Schema.

Changed the Schema to `varchar` and I was all set!